# Search Filter with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a basic search filter where you search and a certain image appears on screen and I am trying to do this with javascript or simple jquery , I cannot seem to make the search work, and I am also wondering if it is possible to do a search based on a class name?

Here is my HTML code

```
 <form onkeyup "function()" > 
      <input type="search" id = "myInput"  placeholder="Search.." name="search" >
    </form> 

 <ul id ="myUL">
    <li class="SupernaturalCookbook"><a href="SupernaturalCookbookProductPage.html"><img src="Images/SupernaturalCookbookCard.jpg" alt="SupernaturalCookbook"></a></li>
  
    
    <li class="MarkOfAthena"><a href="MarkOfAthena.html"><img src="Images/MarkOfAthenaCard.jpg" alt="MarkOfAthena"></a></li>
 
    
    <li class="Instinct"><a href="Instinct.html"><img src="Images/InstinctCard.jpg" alt="Instinct"></a></li>

   
    <li class="CaminoIsland"><a href="CaminoIsland.html"><img src="Images/CaminoIslandCard.jpg" alt="caminoisland"></a></li>


    <li class="TheLuckyOne"><a href="TheLuckyOne.html"><img src="Images/TheLuckyOneCard.jpg" alt="theluckyone"></a></li>


    <li class="TheWhistler"><a href="TheWhistler.html"><img src="Images/TheWhistlerCard.jpg" alt="thewhistler"></a></li>


    <li class="Greenlights"><a href="Greenlights.html"><img src="Images/GreenlightsCard.jpg" alt="greenlights"></a></li>


    <li class="SeaOfMonsters"><a href="SeaOfMonsters.html"><img src="Images/SeaOfMonstersCard.jpg" alt="seaofmonsters"></a></li>



    <li class="SerpentShadows"><a href="SerpentShadows.html"><img src="Images/SerpentShadowsCard.jpg" alt="serpentshadows"></a></li>


    <li class="FromCrookToCook"><a href="FromCrookToCook.html"><img src="Images/FromCrookToCookCard.jpg" alt="fromcrooktocook"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my Javascript code:

```
var input = document.getElementById('myInput');
input.onkeyup = function () {
var filter = myInput.value.toUpperCase();
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    var name = lis[i].getElementsByClassName('class')[0].innerHTML;
    if (name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0) 
        lis[i].style.display = 'list-item';
    else
        lis[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what others added, please keep in mind that `onkeyup` only triggers when someone releases a key. However, there are other ways to change the input of an input field such as cut, paste, clear, etc. To make sure you have covered all the aspects, you can wrap your code in a named function and bind it to the following events

```
function search_images(){
    ///code goes here
}

input.onkeyup = search_images
input.onchange = search_images
input.onpaste = search_images
input.oncut = search_images
input.oninput = search_images
```

Also, be sure to RESET the filter if the input is empty. An alternative solution is as follows:-

```js
function search_images() {
    let filter = this.value.toUpperCase();
    let lis = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('li'));

    if (filter.length > 0) {
        lis.forEach(li => {
            if (Array.from(li.classList).join(" ").toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) >= 0) {
                li.style.display = "list-item"
            } else {
                li.style.display = "none"
            }
        })

    } else {
        lis.forEach(li => li.style.display = "list-item")
    }

}

const input = document.getElementById('myInput');

input.onkeyup = search_images
input.onchange = search_images
input.onpaste = search_images
input.oncut = search_images
input.oninput = search_images
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="search" id="myInput" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
</form>

<ul id="myUL">
    <li class="SupernaturalCookbook">
        <a href="SupernaturalCookbookProductPage.html"> <img src="Images/SupernaturalCookbookCard.jpg" alt="SupernaturalCookbook"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="MarkOfAthena">
        <a href="MarkOfAthena.html"><img src="Images/MarkOfAthenaCard.jpg" alt="MarkOfAthena"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="Instinct">
        <a href="Instinct.html"><img src="Images/InstinctCard.jpg" alt="Instinct"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="CaminoIsland">
        <a href="CaminoIsland.html"><img src="Images/CaminoIslandCard.jpg" alt="caminoisland"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="TheLuckyOne">
        <a href="TheLuckyOne.html"><img src="Images/TheLuckyOneCard.jpg" alt="theluckyone"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="TheWhistler">
        <a href="TheWhistler.html"><img src="Images/TheWhistlerCard.jpg" alt="thewhistler"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="Greenlights">
        <a href="Greenlights.html"><img src="Images/GreenlightsCard.jpg" alt="greenlights"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="SeaOfMonsters">
        <a href="SeaOfMonsters.html"><img src="Images/SeaOfMonstersCard.jpg" alt="seaofmonsters"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="SerpentShadows">
        <a href="SerpentShadows.html"><img src="Images/SerpentShadowsCard.jpg" alt="serpentshadows"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="FromCrookToCook">
        <a href="FromCrookToCook.html"><img src="Images/FromCrookToCookCard.jpg" alt="fromcrooktocook"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you!, it still wasn't working 100% and I have spent most of the time trying to figure out what I did wrong, this worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = document.getElementById('myInput');

input.onkeyup = function () {
    var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        var name = lis[i].className; // takes the classname
        if (name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) >= 0) //Changed this part
            lis[i].style.display = 'list-item';
        else
            lis[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

`indexOf` method returns -1 if not found, else it will be greater than or equal than 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter by class name, replace this line ...

```
var name = lis[i].getElementsByClassName('class')[0].innerHTML;
```

... with this:

```
var name = lis[i].className;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please try to provide a complete answer having taken your time. (especially in first attempts). Please read this: [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)